# Is it possible to use multiple .get on app.route?

Tags: node.js, express

```
app.route('/users')
   .post(user.post)
   .get(user.get)
   .get(user.everyone)
   .put(user.update)
   .delete(user.delete);
```

I have ran into the problem of my function using two res.send, so I am getting the 'Error: cannot set header after they are sent.' error, to fix this I have turned it into two functions which I am trying to use two .get on the app.route, but it seems I can only use one as when I use two the second one doesn't work.

Is there a way I could use two .get on one app.route?
If not, what are my options to get around this problem?

Comment: `/users` will have at most one route of each kind of method. To have two get use `/users/:id` and `/users` for get single user by id and get users list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create separate routes for each api endpoint like this:

```
app.route('/users').get(req, res) => {
//Get all users
});

app.route('/users:/id').get(req, res) => {
   //Get specific user
});

app.route('/users').post(req, res) => {
   //Create new user
});

app.route('/users/:id').put(req, res) => {
   //Update user
});

app.route('/users/:id').delete(req, res) => {
   //Delete user
});
```

Comment: and if I am not wrong, instead of sending the response (res.send()), you can call `next()` and i think it will pass to next `get()`

Answer (score 0):

Once res.send is called, means your server has sent the response to the browser or whatever. you can't change the already sent response and its header.

You can use multiple callbacks on one route and one method(post,get)

An array of callback functions can handle a route. For example:

```
var cb0 = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('CB0')
  next()
}

var cb1 = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('CB1')
  next()
}

var cb2 = function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello from C!')
}

app.get('/example/c', [cb0, cb1, cb2])
```

Comment: This is a middleware implementation. Business logic shouldnt be applied like this, instead, if there are several steps that need to be implemented in sequence, we should should promises / async-await logic inside the route callback

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use multiple HTTP requests either its **.get** or **.post** but with different params. or routes.